# How to center align text in div

Tags: html, css

I'd like to center align the text both vertically and horizontally inside this div. So it has equal padding above and below.

How do I do this with my current code? my Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hr2aLrc0/

```html
<div style="height:300px;background:url('http://placehold.it/600x300') 0 0 no-repeat;background-size:cover">
    
    <h1>Your Title</h1>
    <p>Title<br />Description</p>
    
</div>
```

Comment: Proper vertical alignment is one of the longstanding missing features from CSS. See [this page](http://www.jakpsatweb.cz/css/css-vertical-center-solution.html) for workarounds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a standard question so a doubt that there no duplicates. ;-)

Extend your style/class with `text-align: center;`

```
<div style="text-align: center; height:300px;background:url('http://placehold.it/600x300') 0 0 no-repeat;background-size:cover">

    <h1>Your Title</h1>
    <p>Title<br />Description</p>

</div>
```

Vertical alignment is not that easy.

It can be done with a java script or if you wrap your div in a `position: absolute` styled div with `top: 0px` and `bottom: 0px;`. Then you can use `margin-top: auto; margin-bottom: auto; height: ???px` to center the inner div.

```
<div style="position: absolute; top: 0; bottom: 0; left:0; right:0; height: auto; width: auto;">
  <div style="margin-top: auto; margin-bottom:auto; text-align: center; height:300px;background:url('http://placehold.it/600x300') 0 0 no-repeat;background-size:cover">

    <h1>Your Title</h1>
    <p>Title<br />Description</p>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Good point in the duplicates. I found this which looks more like what I require: http://jsfiddle.net/CtH9k/

Comment: Yes this fiddle will also work. But I'm not sure that it would work with H1 tags. But it is possible and then it would be a good solution. I have been edited my answer to show you another way.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```css
div {
  width: 250px;
  height: 100px;
  line-height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div style="height:300px;background:url('http://placehold.it/600x300') 0 0 no-repeat;background-size:cover">
    
    <h1>Your Title</h1>
    <p>Title<br />Description</p>
    
</div>
```